# Proof Verification: Equivalent Condition for Covering

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

This is a question from an already-submitted homework, which I'm not sure was right. There were two lemmas which I used (which I'm fairly certain are correct), so I'll include the statements but not the proofs of those.

**Statement to prove:** A continuous surjective map $p\colon\widetilde{X}\to X$ between spaces $\widetilde{X}$ and $X$ is a covering map if and only if for each point $a\in X$ its fibre $F_a$ is a discrete subspace of the total space $\widetilde{X}$ and there exists an open neighbourhood $V(a)$ and a homeomorphism $h\colon p^{-1}[V(a)]\to V(a)\times F_a$ such that $p|_{p^{-1}[V(a)]}=\pi_1h$ as maps from $p^{-1}[V(a)]$ to $V(a)$.

**Lemma 1:** Let $(\widetilde{X},X,p)$ be a covering. Then its fibre $F_x$ is a discrete subspace of the total space $\widetilde{X}$ for any point $x\in X$.

**Lemma 2:**  Let $\{U_\alpha\colon\alpha\in A\}$ be a disjoint finite family of sets such that $U_\alpha\cong U$ for all $\alpha\in A$. Then there exists a homeomorphism $\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A} U_\alpha\cong U\times A$.

**Proof attempt:** Denote $(*)$ to be the condition that there exists an open neighbourhood $V(a)$ and a homeomorphism $h\colon p^{-1}[V(a)]\to V(a)\times F_a$ such that $p|_{p^{-1}[V(a)]}=\pi_1h$ as maps from $p^{-1}[V(a)]$ to $V(a)$.

In one direction, suppose $p$ is a covering map. Since by Lemma 1 we know $F_a$ is a discrete subspace of the total space, we only need to show $(*)$ holds. By definition of a covering map, for all $a\in X$ there exists a $V(a)$ such that $p^{-1}[V(a)]=\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}V_\alpha$ for a family of open sets $\{V_\alpha\colon\alpha\in A\}$, and $p|_{V_\alpha}\colon V_\alpha\cong V(a)$ for all $\alpha\in A$.

Since by $\#A=\#F_a$, the existence of a homeomorphism is already given by Lemma 2. To see that $p|_{p^{-1}[V(a)]}=\pi_1h$, consider that $p|_{p^{-1}[V(a)]}\colon \widetilde{x}\mapsto x$ for some $x\in X$. $\widetilde{x}\in V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in A$, and by Lemma 2 we have $h'\colon \widetilde{x}\mapsto(\widetilde{x},\alpha)\mapsto(x',\alpha)$. In general $x'\neq x$, but we only need to choose a permutation $\sigma\colon (x',\alpha)\mapsto(x,\alpha)$, where $h:=\sigma h'$. Then $\pi_1\colon (x,\alpha)\mapsto x$ and thus $\pi_1\sigma h'=\pi_1 h=p|_{V_\alpha}$ given by
$$\widetilde{x}\mapsto(\widetilde{x},a)\mapsto(x',a)\mapsto(x,a).$$
Since this equality holds for all $V_\alpha$, it also holds for their union, so
$$\pi_1 h=p|_{\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}V_\alpha}=p|_{p^{-1}[V(a)]}.$$
In the other direction suppose both $(*)$ holds and $F_a$ is a discrete subspace. Then $\pi_1$ itself is the covering map. To see this take an arbitrary $a\in X$, and note $\pi_1^{-1}[V(a)]=V(a)\times\bigcup_{x\in F_a}\{x\}$. Then $\pi_1|_{V(a)\times\{x\}}$ maps homeomorphically to $V(a)$, so every $a\in X$ has an admissible open neighbourhood $V(a)$. Moreover this is open in the product topology since singletons are open in a discrete space (and $F_a$ is discrete by assumption).

I know this is rather long, but I'd appreciate if anyone could show me if/where I went wrong. Thank you very much!